# 2 Slider Input Combination

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the values of two slider inputs in order to change the image above the slider. For example if the value of slider 1 is 10 and the value of slider 2 is 80 it will change the image.

I have had success completing this with one slider, however when trying to use two slider it seems to mess up. Below is the code of the one slider solution.

P.s I took the slider from w3school on the link. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_rangeslider.asp

Thanks for reading,

```js
var fatslider = document.getElementById("myRange1");
    var fatoutput = document.getElementById("demo1");
    fatoutput.innerHTML = fatslider.value; // Display the default slider value

    // Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)

    fatslider.oninput = function() {
        fatoutput.innerHTML = this.value;
        if(this.value == 0){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat01muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 5){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat02muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 10){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat03muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 15){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat04muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 20){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat05muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 25){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat06muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 30){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat08muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 35){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat09muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 40){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat10muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 45){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat11muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 50){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat12muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 55){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat13muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 60){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat14muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 65){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat15muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 70){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat16muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 75){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat17muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 80){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat18muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 85){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat19muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 90){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat20muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 95){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat21muscle01.png";;
        } else if(this.value == 100){
            document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src="images/bodytype/fat22muscle01.png";;
        } 
    }
```

```css
.fat-slidecontainer {
width: 100%; /* Width of the outside container */
}

/* The slider itself */
.fat-slider {
-webkit-appearance: none;  /* Override default CSS styles */
appearance: none;
width: 100%; /* Full-width */
height: 25px; /* Specified height */
background: #d3d3d3; /* Grey background */
outline: none; /* Remove outline */
opacity: 0.7; /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
-webkit-transition: .2s; /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
transition: opacity .2s;
}

/* Mouse-over effects */
.fat-slider:hover {
opacity: 1; /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
}

/* The slider handle (use -webkit- (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) and -moz- 
(Firefox) to override default look) */ 
.fat-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
-webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default look */
appearance: none;
width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
background: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}

.fat-slider::-moz-range-thumb {
width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
background: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}
.fat-slidecontainer {
width: 100%; /* Width of the outside container */
}

/* The slider itself */
.muscle-slider {
-webkit-appearance: none;  /* Override default CSS styles */
appearance: none;
width: 100%; /* Full-width */
height: 25px; /* Specified height */
background: #d3d3d3; /* Grey background */
outline: none; /* Remove outline */
opacity: 0.7; /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
-webkit-transition: .2s; /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
transition: opacity .2s;
}

/* Mouse-over effects */
.muscle-slider:hover {
opacity: 1; /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
}

/* The slider handle (use -webkit- (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) and -moz- 
(Firefox) to override default look) */ 
.muscle-slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
-webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default look */
appearance: none;
width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
background: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}

.muscle-slider::-moz-range-thumb {
width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
background: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}
```

```html
<center>
 <img src="images/bodytype/fat10muscle01.png" id="quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image">
<p>Select Fat Level</p>
<div class="fat-slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="fat-slider" id="myRange1">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo1"></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to explain what do you want to achieve and how is it messed up.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I wasn't clear, I want two slider inputs. The project I am doing has a fat slider and a muscle slider, the diagram/image above should increase/decrease in fat, increase/decrease in muscle and increase/decrease in both. I have no idea why it doesn't work tbh, it does the most random things.

Comment: Okay, now I understand your basic problems. Can you create a JSFiddle, so we could see how is it failing?

Comment: Hi, turns out I made a simple mistake with not adding a close curly bracket, now I am unsure of how to fix the IF statement to include both functions, here's the link to the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/x297sq6v/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make sure that your values are in harmony with your expectations. Since your code aims to support values of 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100. In order to achieve this the minimum value needs to be 5, the maximum value needs to be 100 and the step needs to be 5:

```
<center>
 <img src="images/bodytype/fat10muscle01.png" id="quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image">
<p>Select Fat Level</p>
<div class="fat-slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="5" max="100" value="50" class="fat-slider" id="myRange1" step="5">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo1"></span></p>
</div>
<p>Select Muscle Level</p>
<div class="muscle-slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="5" max="100" value="50" class="muscle-slider" id="myRange2" step="5">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo2"></span></p>
</div>
</center>
```

Now, let's fix the Javascript:

```
var fatslider = document.getElementById("myRange1");
    var fatoutput = document.getElementById("demo1");
    fatoutput.innerHTML = fatslider.value; // Display the default slider value

    var muscleslider = document.getElementById("myRange2");
    var muscleoutput = document.getElementById("demo2");
    muscleoutput.innerHTML = muscleslider.value; // Display the default slider value

var mapSliderToPicture = {
    "0": "01",
    "5": "01",
    "10": "02",
    "15": "03",
    "20": "04",
    "25": "05",
    "30": "06",
    "35": "07",
    "40": "08",
    "45": "09",
    "50": "10",
    "55": "11",
    "60": "12",
    "65": "13",
    "70": "14",
    "75": "15",
    "80": "16",
    "85": "17",
    "90": "18",
    "95": "19",
    "100": "20",
};

function updateImage(fat, muscle) {
    console.log(document.getElementById("quiz-q1-current-bodytype-image").src = `images/bodytype/fat${mapSliderToPicture[fat]}muscle${mapSliderToPicture[muscle]}.png`);
}

muscleslider.oninput = function() {
    updateImage(parseInt(document.getElementById("myRange1").value), parseInt(muscleoutput.innerHTML = this.value));
}

fatslider.oninput = function() {
    updateImage(parseInt(fatoutput.innerHTML = this.value), parseInt(document.getElementById("myRange2").value));
}
```

Exaplanation in points:

- I left the definition of your objects as they were
- I created a mapping between expected input values and their matches
- I created a function which updates the image, using a literal template for code clarity, note that only the numbers in the picture location are computed here (sorry about the console.log, the pictures in your example are broken, making it difficult to test)
- I created `oninput` events to both sliders calling the same function and passing correct parameters

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0cb6hmfs/1/

Comment: @JasonSingh you are welcome. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @JasonSingh there is a white checkbox under the number at the left of this answer, by clicking on that you can accept an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers